# How to use material-ui theme along with redux in gatsby

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux, material-ui

I am using material-ui theme along with redux-toolit in gatsby.

My theme.ts file:

```
import { createMuiTheme } from "@material-ui/core";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { State } from "./Types/SliceTypes";

export const Theme = () => {

const islit = useSelector((state: State) => state.themes.value);

const theme = createMuiTheme({
    palette: {
      type: islit ? "light" : "dark",
    },
  });

  return theme;
}
```

Now When I import this Theme in gatsby-browser and gatsby-ssr file it give an error. *Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component*

Even if I don't use islit and use theme only that is inside the Theme function the code still doesn't work.

My gatsby-browser.js and gatsby-ssr.js file:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from './src/Global/store';
import { ThemeProvider } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import { Theme } from "./src/Global/theme";

export const wrapRootElement = ({ element }) => {
  
  return <Provider store={store}><ThemeProvider theme={Theme()}>{element}</ThemeProvider></Provider>;
};
```

My gatsby-config.js file:

```
plugins: [
`gatsby-plugin-react-helmet`,
`gatsby-plugin-material-ui`,
`gatsby-plugin-image`,
```

My package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "gatsby-starter-default",
  "private": true,
  "description": "A simple starter to get up and developing quickly with Gatsby",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "author": "Kyle Mathews <mathews.kyle@gmail.com>",
  "dependencies": {
    "@contentful/rich-text-react-renderer": "^14.1.3",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.3",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.5.1",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.3",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.3",
    "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.16",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.22.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.22.0",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "firebase": "^8.4.1",
    "firebaseui": "^4.8.0",
    "gatsby": "^3.3.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-firebase": "^0.2.0-beta.4",
    "gatsby-plugin-gatsby-cloud": "^2.2.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-image": "^1.2.1",
    "gatsby-plugin-manifest": "^3.2.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-material-ui": "^3.0.1",
    "gatsby-plugin-offline": "^4.2.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-react-helmet": "^4.2.0",
    "gatsby-plugin-sharp": "^3.2.1",
    "gatsby-source-contentful": "^5.3.0",
    "gatsby-source-filesystem": "^3.2.0",
    "gatsby-transformer-remark": "^4.0.0",
    "gatsby-transformer-sharp": "^3.2.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-helmet": "^6.1.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.3",
    "typescript": "^4.2.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/react-helmet": "^6.1.1",
    "prettier": "2.2.1"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "gatsby"
  ],
  "license": "0BSD",
  "scripts": {
    "build": "gatsby build",
    "develop": "gatsby develop",
    "format": "prettier --write \"**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx,json,md}\"",
    "start": "npm run develop",
    "serve": "gatsby serve",
    "clean": "gatsby clean",
    "test": "echo \"Write tests! -> https://gatsby.dev/unit-testing\" && exit 1"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby-starter-default"
  },
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar set up and was able to solve this by following this setup recommended by MUI; https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/tree/next/examples/gatsby

In the file gatsby/plugins/gatsby-plugin-top-layout/TopLayout.js you can add your redux Provider;

```
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { ThemeProvider } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import { Theme } from "../../src/Global/theme";
import store from '../../src/Global/store';

...

      <Provider store={store}>
        <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
          {/* CssBaseline kickstart an elegant, consistent, and simple baseline to build upon. */}
          <CssBaseline />
          {props.children}
        </ThemeProvider>
      </Provider>

...
```